# How to automatically replace links with their title on SE?

Tags: support

When I reference a question in meta SO, it is turned into a `<a href>` link, with the uninformative link which often doesn't reveal more than `stackoverflow.com/questions/<question-id>/` being replaced by the question title. In SO this is not the case. How can I turn this on as a preference by default (if it's not a optional feature yet, see this as a feature request)?

Comment: It [should work the same on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/69483#69483), for links within SO. Any example that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Dupe, but on the wrong site: [What limitations does converting question links to links with titles have?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/what-limitations-does-converting-question-links-to-links-with-titles-have/)

Comment: @Arjan Now I got, I pasted links starting with  `stackoverflow.com/questions/.../...` instead of `http://stackoverflow.com/...` which are recognized as links and corrected by firefox silently, but not masqueraded with the title of the question. Would it make sense to change the feature request to masquerade links with omitted protocol prefix, too?

Comment: ...example? It really should work (and it's not done by Firefox), if you read the 2 links I gave you. (As an aside, I don't think "masquerade" is the correct term.)

Comment: @Arjan example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350671/inner-exception-with-traceback-in-python/13018468?noredirect=1#comment35455107_13018468 (works as link, but is not replaced with title)

Comment: Ah, that's a link to a comment. Maybe that matters? Surely you'd better not link to comments from posts, as comments are easily deleted. Also, automatic conversion is only supported in posts, not in comments. (But that's just the same on Meta.) Still then: even [that link works for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lqMse.png).

Comment: As for comments: [Replace links with the current question title in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments) (declined).

Comment: @Arjan I should have made a clearer difference between comment and question links (I didn't pay attention). Thanks for the link to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments. Issue should be discussed there.